# Upload Photos one at a time with a JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, objective-c-blocks, background-process

I need some help trying to figure out some logic / best method.

I have an iOS app that uploads pictures. I have a server that responds ***Success*** or ***Fail*** after each picture is uploaded.

If I have 5 pictures waiting to be uploaded (maybe no internet access, or the user only wants to upload on WIFI), I need a way to upload each picture individually, wait for that picture to respond success or fail, (fail will try again) and then move on to the next picture, all on a background thread so the user can keep working.

Now I have most of the queuing logic ready. The issue I am having a problem with is the doing each picture singularly, getting that JSON response (success || fail) then moving on to the next.

I currently use:

```
 if (photoQueue.count > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < photoQueue.count; i++) {
            if([self processPhoto:[photoQueue objectAtIndex:i]]){
                [photoQueue removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            } else {
                  NSLog(@"PHOTO UPLOAD FAILED");
            }

        }
    }
```

Where process photo returns a `bool`, but this isn't working correctly and seems to duplicate photos or it misses photos altogether.

I have toyed with the idea of BLOCKS, Doing the photo upload in there and parsing the json response and passing that back as the return BOOL. But I do not know enough about them to step through however many photos.

```
[self doPhotoUpload:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
   //Do the photo upload here and parse the json response and pass that as the return BOOL
}];
```

How do I step-by-step through each individual photo and upload?

Comment: You may try to do it in a while loop until the queue is empty, and in the case of failure, put the photo to the end of the `photoQueue`.

Comment: If you really want to upload one at a time, the simple pattern is to have a queue of uploads (e.g. a mutable array), start the first upload, and in the completion handler and/or didFinish delegate method, you check to see if it succeeded, and if so, initiate the next one. Having said that, I question the prudence of uploading them sequentially, as that's much slower than uploading them concurrently.

Comment: if you're deleting entries from `photoQueue` at the same time as you are incrementing through the array, you will miss entries - if you remove the entry at index = 0, and then move on to the next one index = 1, but because you have removed the first entry, what WAS index = 1, is now index = 0.  Better to count down if you need the index, or to use something like `for photo in photoQueue`  You can always get round the problem by flagging entries for deletion / or to show success, and tidying up afterwards

Comment: @Russell thanks! i didn't even see that bug!

Comment: everything is easy - the second or third time you get hit by it!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small number of photos - why not create a separate background task for each one, and have it retry as often as you need?  You will need to update the data model once you have finished - success or fail - but you don't need to worry about processing each one in turn

Depending on how you want to handle the retries, could be something like this ...

```
if (photoQueue.count > 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i < photoQueue.count; i++) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             if([self processPhoto:[photoQueue objectAtIndex:i]]){
                 [photoQueue removeObjectAtIndex:i];
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"PHOTO UPLOAD FAILED");
            }
    });
```